Shadow catcher layer looking weird
Trying to build up a decent reflection catcher to mix it with shadow catcher.
Using a plane with shadow catcher on first render layer and reflective plane for the second layer.
Why does the shadow catcher layer looks weird (bright colored reflection) in the compositor window, while the shadow is looking fine in the viewport?
In the compositor there are no nodes used, just simple noodle from shadow catcher layer to the viewer node.


Stupid question: is the shadow catcher plane reflective? If you just want the shadow, do not make it reflective. If you want a reflection plane for compositing, this has to be a different plane than the shadow catcher.

Your question isn't stupid. Both planes, visible in reflection layer and catcher in the main layer have the same reflective material.
I set up this test scene to figure out the pipeline for my main project.
It has a chrome surface which is very damaged (rust, grunge). There's also an object on top of it. I need to render that object together with its shadow and reflection.
This image and the black knob are the closest illustration of the scene that I'm working on - https://i.imgur.com/t13oQlK.jpeg

Well, shadows in reality are not just black and white or greyscale. They get a tint like for example, in the open air from the blue sky even though the sun does not reach it, or bouncing off from colored objects etc (or from reflecting colored objects). The shadow catcher pass in the Compositor shows those colors as well - while using the shadow catcher directly in render only gives a grey shadow. To get at least less color in the shadow catcher pass you should use a white material, Roughness at 1 and Specular at 0.

That's the thing. I want the shadow not to be uniform and follow the surface reflectivity pattern in the compositor just as in the viewport https://i.imgur.com/EdJf8al.png
